# How to merge from branch to trunk in Eclipse using Subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, subclipse

I am using the Subclipse plugin in eclipse IDE, to commit and update my code. I am in need of merging code from branch to trunk. As a part of it, I am facing this issue.
Here's my workaround steps to merge the branch to trunk.

- Right click on the project -> Team -> Merge.
- Select Merge two different trees.
- I have set From URL to my branch. 
  Eg: http://abc.com:40/branches/appi1.1/src/demo.properties
- I have also set To URL to my trunk 
  Eg: http://abc.com:40/trunk/appi/src
- In both from and to URL sections, I have selected head revision radio button.
- In the console, I got the message: Merge completed abnormally

Lucidly, here's my error alert from eclipse IDE.
[image]

P.S: In my trunk code, there exists no demo.properties, but it's there in the branch code.

Comment: Have you tried another SVN connector? SVNKit instead of JavaHL?

Comment: Nope, I did not try that.

Comment: I also suggest using SVNKit

Comment: https://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=MEuUjb&freeformpage=Merge%20Client

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have not installed the CollabNet Merge Client from the Subclipse update site you should do so.  The Subclipse merge option has not really been updated for the merge tracking support since Subversion 1.5.

Your merge parameters are definitely not correct.  The "To URL" is not the target for the merge, your working copy is.  The From and To URL are the two URL/revision ranges to diff to produce the merge that you want to apply to your working copy.  In most cases, the two URL's should be the same and the revision numbers should change to reflect the range of revisions you want to merge.

The new UI introduced with the CollabNet Merge Client resolves these issues and makes it much easier to perform the correct merge.

You should avoid merging a specific file, when using Subversion.  Ideally you should merge the entire tree, /branches/appi1.1 in your example.